# getting the amplitude of the microphone in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, windows-phone-8

I want to get the real time amplitude of the microphone input in windows phone. What is the simplest and efficient way to achieve this ?

Comment: Look at this article :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361022/processing-audio-on-fly-c-wp7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the amplitude, you will have to handle the BufferReady event of the Microphone class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg442302(v=vs.105).aspx

Setup code

```
Microphone microphone = Microphone.Default;
microphone.BufferReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(microphone_BufferReady);
microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

byte[] buffer;
buffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(microphone.BufferDuration)];

microphone.Start();
```

Event handler block

```
void microphone_BufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    microphone.GetData(buffer);


    for(int i = 0; i< buffer.Length; i+=2)
    {
        //The value of sample is the amplitude of the signal
        short sample = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[2] { buffer[i], buffer[i + 1] }, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It throws a "System.NullReferenceException" at "microphone.BufferReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(microphone_BufferReady);". Could you please fix that ?

Comment: I could fix it. Just had to enable ID_CAP_MICROPHONE in WMAppManifest.xml.