# Real time audio processing problems with Microphone in Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, audio-recording

Following the lead on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361022/processing-audio-on-fly-c-wp7) I have arrived on a very particular problem that I am not able to solve.  In my application, I am attempting to visualize audio data much like it is done in the example provided in the example using microphone class and data from the microphone buffer.  I am also using a **DispatcherTimer** to keep track of time which is displayed in the UI.

Interestingly enough, I am noticing somewhat of rather big delays in audio visualization of this data (I would say around 0.5 seconds delay for every 20 seconds of recording) in comparison to the timer. If possible, how can I visualize the data accurately in real time so there is not a discrepancy in time displayed by the **DispatcherTimer** and the UI which visualizes data.

It may be of interest that the interval for the dispatcher timer tick event is 100 milliseconds and the same for microphone buffer ready even.

What action should I take to reduce the delay between audio visualization and the time as shown by **DispatcherTimer**.

Code
DispatcherTimer

```
timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
timer.Start();

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    numSeconds++;

    if (numSeconds%10==0)
        TimeTextBlock.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(numSeconds/10).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
}
```

Code for Microphone

```
microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
buffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(microphone.BufferDuration)];
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
microphone.BufferReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Microphone_BufferReady);
microphone.Start();

private void Microphone_BufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    //Visualize buffer
    //other logic
 }
```

Comment: 1. Could you please ask a question? 2. Could you post the code in question please?

Comment: @Adam Hi, sorry about that.  I posted it now.